# Sharepoint 2010 Taxonomy: How to get a flat list of terms for a termSet?

Tags: taxonomy

I was wondering if there is any way to get all descendant terms for a termSet, not only direct children, but the complete set as a termsCollection.

The TermSet.Terms Property will return only the direct children.

Without having to itterate and build a client side list, is there a built in quicker way?

Something like TermSet.GetTerms(bool includeDescendants) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mmm - I just found this

```
TermSet.GetAllTerms Method
```

If you work for Microsoft and implemented this method - I love you!